# Browse only free streaming Amazon Prime videos?

Tags: amazon, user-interface, video-streaming

I've got a subscription to Amazon Prime, which gives me some selection of their videos streaming for free.

I'd like to be use this like I do Netflix--search for a movie I'm interested in and see if I can stream it.  Browse to related videos.  Etcetera.

But since Amazon *also* offers streaming rentals, I'm constantly wading through videos that aren't free to watch, and it's hard to tell the difference without clicking on each one.  At this point, the streaming video service seems like more trouble than it's worth.

Am I missing something?  Is there a way for me to lock browsing and searching to free streaming titles, and not see books or rentals or household cleaning products when I look for a movie?

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/b/ref=sa_menu_aiv_piv?ie=UTF8&node=2676882011 maybe? Also, if you search instant video instead of all of Amazon, you won't see books, etc...

Comment: Thanks @derobert.  That's as good as I've been able to get.  It doesn't really compare to Netflix, and I was hoping that Amazon (or some 3rd party) had made an interface specifically for watching Prime videos.  Maybe I'd be better off trying Boxee or watching through a video game console.

Comment: Not quite what you want but the [storefront](https://www.primevideo.com/storefront/home) usually only shows free content and it makes good recommendations based on your past viewed content

Answer (score 3):

For search results, there's a "Prime Eligible" checkbox at the side bar.

[image: Search result with Prime Eligible option on]